# Prevent image distortion with image within transformed div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to adjust the transform on the background for this codepen. The goal would be to adjust the placeholder images so that it sits in it's normal position before the `mouseenter`, but still have the div rotated so it's a diamond square. As you can see, I have a jQuery animation that will come into play as well. Here is the Codepen:

http://codepen.io/pdnellius/pen/EfkHl

EDIT: I've updated my code to reflect my changes that I've made which gets the effect 90% there, however this feels really hacky.

I had to use a `<img>` tag instead of a background image on a `<div>` to achieve the desired effect. Can anyone recommend a solution that could center the `<img>` while maintaining the proportions when it goes 100% width? Usually I would use a background image with a contain property to achieve this effect, but since I've had to use a `<img>` tag in order to get this effect working, I'm unable to do that. I've updated the Codepen above to reflect my progress.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="diamond">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/2100/2800" class="diamond-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-top: 15em;

  }

.diamond {
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  background: aquamarine;
  margin: 0% 50%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.diamond:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(background.png) 0 0 repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.diamond-img {
    height: 60em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 30%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 96%;
}
```

**JS**

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

     $(".diamond").on("mouseenter", function(){
       console.log("entered .diamond");
      $(".diamond").animate({
        transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
        transformOrigin: '0 0',
        margin: '0 0',
        width: '100%',
        height: '40em'
      }), $(".diamond-img").animate({
        width: '100%',
        height: 'auto', 
        transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
      }),

  $("#wrapper").animate({
      marginTop: '0'
    })
  }).on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(".diamond").animate({
    transform: 'rotate(-45deg)',
    transformOrigin: '0 100%',
    width: '30em',
    height: '30em',
    margin: '0 50%'
  }), $(".diamond-img").animate({
    height: '60em',
    transform: 'rotate(45deg)',
    width: '45em',
    // transformOriginX: '30%',
    // transformOriginY: '96%'
  }),
    $("#wrapper").animate({
      marginTop: '15em'
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: You want it to be a square in the middle before mouse over?

Comment: well the overflow would be hidden, I could adjust that accordingly. The image would be on square horizontally with the page though rather than rotated 45 deg.

Comment: Add code to the question as well.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, because in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j52fp/ - I've just used CSS. What am I missing?

Comment: @TimSPQR, not quite what I'm looking for. The animation/transition to full-bleed is already present in my Codepen, I just need the initial state (pre-mouseover) to have the background image adjusted to be look normal. Presumably I would need it to offset the 45deg that the diamond square has been rotated. Is there a way to add a transform to a background image only?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from [THIS](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/) webpage, we modify your fiddle with a :before kludge to get this - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j52fp/1/).

Any better?

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  margin-top: 15em;
}

.diamond {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  margin: 0% 50%;
}
.diamond:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/2000x2000) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.diamond:hover:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/2000x2000) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't the solution I am looking for. Thanks for your try though!